# Properly extending an interface

Tags: typescript, model

I'm wondering if there is a better approach for designing a model for my app, as I think it's not that clean. Might be the wrong place here to ask, but maybe you're willing to help

**Scenario**

Admin registers a candidate for a test:

```
interface PreCandidate {
  gender: 'male' | 'female';
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  note?: string;
  invited: Date;
  stage: 'invited' | 'registered';
}
```

Then, the candidate gets an invitation mail and proceeds a sign up with some additional information:

```
interface CandidateDetails {
  birthDate: Date;
  address: {
    street: string;
    postal_code: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
  };
}
```

This is all stored in the database:

```
type CandidateData = PreCandidate & CandidateDetails;
```

And afterwards used in the app as

```
interface Candidate extends CandidateData {
  id: string;
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me .. but I think this is a better forum for the question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir No, this is asking for design advice about code not yet in function. That's explicitly off-topic per the [Code Review help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).